# Unity free form light shape editing not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can not figure out how to extend my light shape in unity editor v 2021. I would expect to drag those points with the left mouse click (same like when I adjust colliders shape), but it only removes that vertex. Is there any special key, or do I accidentaly turned on some function?

It is free form light 2D.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an identical error and kept getting "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range" when editing in the inspector.

This [Unity Forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/urp-light2d-freeform-shape-editing-at-runtime.917300/) states that there is only a get property, no set property for the freeform light editor which may be causing this error.

In short, I think this is a bug that Unity has not fixed. 2D Lights are still labeled as "Experimental".

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because the light in question was a grandchild of an object with a Grid Layout component.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).